# insert 0 in to empty cells when calculating percentage difference with google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am calculating the % increase within a column ('total'), but there are some empty rows. if the row is empty i would like to insert a zero but i cant..i am very new to google sheets! any advice would be great. Thank you!

```
total  increase  what_i_want
10               0
9      -10.0     -10
0      -100.0    -100
0                0
15               0
29     93.3      93.3
56     93.1      93.1
```

the command that gives the output in the 'increase' column

```
=Iferror(IF(CONCATENATE(I3:I4)="0","0",(I4-I3)/I3*100))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add zero before you close the formula for `iferror`, give it re-run then it shall return the correct output:

```
=Iferror(IF(CONCATENATE(A2:A3)="0","0",(A2-A1)/A1*100),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ROW()=2,0,IFERROR((I4-I3)/I4*100,0))
```

should work.

Idea : 2nd row = 0. put 0 in other cell if #div/0 is detected.